# How to find the time of newly created/altered columns of an existing table?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working on a project in `amazon redshift` and I need to find the data for the below 3 points.

> 1. Created time of a table across all schemas
> 2. Owner/user of the table created
> 3. Plus, time and any schema changes of an existing table [that underwent newly created/altered columns].

I was managed to solve #1 and #2 using system tables `pg_class_info` & `pg_namespace` [for #1] and `pg_tables` [for #2] but stuck with point #3. **Can someone help me figure out ways to achieve the #3? Please help**.

Note: Any better suggestions for #1 and #2 is also welcomed.

Comment: It is amazon redshift

Answer (score 0):

For the third requirement, there is not a direct answer
On the other hand by querying the system view STL_QUERY you might find what you are looking for

Here is the sample query

```
select
userid, starttime, querytxt 
from STL_QUERY 
where querytxt like '%alter%table%'
limit 10;
```